# Mysql `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON` error when print comment inside a cursor loop

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I saw this error:

> Error
> Static analysis:
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

What is the problem to print comments by `select 'my message'` inside a loop after fetch a cursor in a stored procedure. In below example `select 'MESSAGE 1'` is OK but `select 'MESSAGE 2'` raise above error when calling a stored procedure. The stored procedure will compile and create successfully.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE testsp3()
BEGIN  
    
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c_id INT;
    DECLARE c_name VARCHAR(50);
    
    DECLARE Get_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name FROM testloop;  

   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
    select 'MESSAGE 1'  ;
    
    OPEN Get_cur;  
    lbl: LOOP  
    
        FETCH Get_cur INTO c_id, c_name;  
        
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE lbl;
        END IF;        
        
        select 'MESSAGE 2'  ;
    END LOOP;  
      
    CLOSE Get_cur;  
  END
  
  //
```

And my table is as below:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | majid |
| 2 | ali |

Comment: I think the actual problem is not the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON` statement, but the `SELECT 'MESSAGE 2' `. From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursor-restrictions.html), `You cannot use a cursor for a statement that generates a result set if the statement is not supported in prepared mode`. So, if you really need to `select something`, maybe you can use temporary table to store that `something` and then select it later outside the cursor.

Comment: @Hermanto Thanks for your comment. So this is a **cursor restrictions**!